# Is there a Firebase security setting to allow only inserts?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using the web client for Firebase, and need to store a mail. Im using the anonymous authentication, in order to ask the user for a mail and store it to the database.
Edit: the use-case is any user(anonymous) storing a mail, simply that. I don-t even need to read anything. I was not sure about using Node as being the option to defining a constraint of "insert only"
 Is there any security rule that allows any user(anonymous) to insert-only ?
The query:
`db.collection("users").doc("nico@nico.com").set({});`
By insert only I mean write only(without deleting or updating)

Comment: There's not enough information here.  When working with security rules, they should always be paired up with specific client queries to allow.  Without knowing the specific query and its constraints, it's not possible to write any rules effectively.  Please edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: Query added. The constraint should be only insert (write?) without delete or update. I think I need to use Node client instead of web client

Answer (score 1):

By insert only I am assuming you mean `create` only which means users can write their email to the database, but they cannot `read`, `update`, or `delete` anything. If this is the case then these rules will work. [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      // Allow create access on all documents to
      // any user signed in to the application.
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null
      allow read, update, delete: if false
    }
  }
}
```

However, you probably only want to grant create access to a specific portion of your database. For example only where that users information should be stored. Using the content owner only rules found in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#content-owner-only) might be a good place to start.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /some_collection/{document} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only authenticated users to be able to create documents in the users collection, and nothing else:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{id} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```